# Can Adobe AIR applications achieve SSO authentication against Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, air, ldap, single-sign-on

I don't know much about AIR apps, but I like what I'm seeing so far.  So now, I'm wondering if this type of app would make sense in the intranet at work.

Before I invest time and effort into ramping up on AIR development, I would like to know:  *is it possible for an AIR app on Windows to do single sign-on authentication against Active Directory?*  I'm thinking of maybe an AIR app that uses a logged on user's Windows credentials to connect to web services hosted on IIS with Windows auth turned on.

I know that IT security would get on my case if I rolled an app that makes a user enter a password.  Any workaround that's not kludgy and accomplishes SSO with AD would be cool too.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully setup Tomcat 6.0.26 running on CentOS 5.4 (Final) with Java 1.6.0_17-b04 using the SPNEGO servlet filter from spnego.sourceforge.net to automatically authenticate WindowsXP SP3 with IE 7.0 against a Windows 2003 R2 Active Directory domain.  In addition, I have an Adobe AIR application developed for use on an intranet that can also authenticate via SPNEGO just like IE7.

Before getting Tomcat working on CentOS, I followed the "pre-flight checklist" and "install guide-tomcat" links at sourceforge.net to get Tomcat working with the SPNEGO filter on a Windows XP server.  Once I got things setup so that IE could auto-authenticate, Adobe AIR just worked.

Once I had the username, I wrote some code to pull user groups from the AD LDAP.  Helpful links for Java LDAP code may be found at starting at http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=726601.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. If SSO works in IE it works in your AIR app. We are currently deploying an app that does just this.

AIR running on Windows will use the SSO settings from Internet Explorer. As long as your users can login with SSO in IE, they can do the same in AIR. This can be done with group policy settings pretty easily: add your site as an Intranet site, enable Integrated Windows Authentication, and you're good to go.

Haven't run into any problems so far. We've tested it with about 10 users. YMMV.

Comment: For David: You can't really pull the credentials per se - you just make the request and Windows does the SSO for you behind the scenes, if you're lucky and managed to get the right combination of IE settings and server auth setup.

We use Apache on Linux so I can't really help with Windows Server details, although I'd imagine it's probably less painful when you've got both server and client inside Microsoft Camp.

Answer (score 0):

Using AIR you can read files from the file system and you can open network connections, so that should get you somewhere.

What would the use of the SSO be? Describing a possible job that this AIR app should perform will help people to give a more helpful answer.

Comment: I was hoping to have an AIR app connect using a logged on user's credentials to web services hosted on IIS that has Windows authentication turned on. For us, it's always a no-no to have users enter passwords into an app. Adobe seems to market to consumers not MS shops, so I figure it's a long shot.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I don't think AIR supports that. If are mainly interested in using flash/flex and not in AIR per se, you could try to create a hybrid application using Zinc or SWF Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Charles,

If you have an example of some code that pulls I.E. credentials, I would be really grateful to see it.  I'm working on building a Flex app that accesses content on a SharePoint server that uses the active directory to authenticate permissions.