# Can we achieve SSO with AIR application

Tags: air, single-sign-on

I see you had a similar requirement to achieve single sign on with AIR application.
Did you achieve SSO with AIR? I am using spring security with CAS and the Adobe technolgies are AIR/FLEX BlazeDS. Thanks in advance.

Vandana

Answer (score 0):

[The use case seems similar to Can Adobe AIR applications achieve SSO authentication against Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499501/can-adobe-air-applications-achieve-sso-authentication-against-active-directory)